# An error in submit form registration FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

When I have submit form in registration **FOSUserBundle** I have this error :

[image]

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Given that the error is "unknown error", you're going to have to be a bit more specific. I.e. show code.

Answer (score 0):

Far too vague to determine an answer for you.  If you inspect the NormalizerFormatter.php file at lines 77 and 82 you can see what it's doing and where the problems are occuring.

NormalizerFormatter.php:

```
76            $count = 1;
77        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
78            if ($count++ >= 1000) {
79                $normalized['...'] = 'Over 1000 items, aborting normalization';
80                break;
81            }
82            $normalized[$key] = $this->normalize($value);
83        }
```